# Maven automate versioning and changelog generation

Tags: maven, version-control, version, versioning, maven-release-plugin

I want to automate version and changelog creation from Git commits. So it's basically the same thing as `npm standard-version` but it's for Maven. So how can I achieve the versioning automatically?

additional information: I want to increase the version at POM file using the Git Commit-lint messages. In npm if you commit features it increases MINOR, and if you commit fix it increases PATCH version automatically at Semantic Versioning and creates a changelog for these changes. I was wondering if there is a similar way for Maven?

Comment: Could you give more details for non-npm-experts on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to increase the version at POM file using the Git Commit-lint messages. In npm if you commit features it increases MINOR, and if you commit fix it increases PATCH version automatically at Semantic Versioning and creates a changelog for these changes. I was wondering if there is a similar function for Maven?

Comment: Sounds cool, but never heard of it in Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a direct way for Maven. However, you can still use [standard-version](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version) to create the changelog and bump up the version. You have to write a script to make package.json and Maven versions same. I used the [Versions Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/set.html) to accomplish it.

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=%npm_package_version% && mvn versions:commit
```