# how to apply semantic versioning to the java maven project to automatically increment the version inside pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, github-actions, semantic-versioning

Can anyone please tell me how to apply the semver to the java maven project? I tried many ways, but I didn't find any useful resources to automatically increase the version when I push the code to the branch. I'm using Github action workflow to deploy the project into GitHub.

Thank you.

Comment: You might be interested in this stack overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57141912/maven-automate-versioning-and-changelog-generation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first approach is to use the command line but you have to configuration the following in your pom file before. You can of course directly [use the command line and put everything on the plain command without this setup](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) but it's very inconvenient

```
  <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.9.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>major</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>set</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
              <newVersion>${parsedVersion.nextMajorVersion}.0.0-SNAPSHOT</newVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>minor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>set</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
              <newVersion>${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT</newVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>patch</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>set</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
              <newVersion>${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}-SNAPSHOT</newVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>parse-version</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
```

By using the above configuration you can change/update the version of your project like this:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set@major
```

This will increment the major version and set minor and patch version to `0`.

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set@minor
```

This will increment the minor version and set patch version to zero.

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set@patch
```

this will increment the patch version. Afterwards you have to commit your changed back into your version control system (for example git).

I recommend to define this kind of setup into a parent pom and reuse it for multiple projects. A detail explanation why and how this works can be found here https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2021/04/05/maven-plugin-configuration/

Using the maven-release-plugin is also an option. It will make also the tags in your version control.